# Firebase emulators: connecting to real database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

In my firestore I want to keep some "almost static" data, like, for example, translations for i18n. When testing everything on my local machine, I'd like to automatically add some data (like missing translations) to that database, so that I would then be anle to use it in the final version.

However, when I'm launching `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore`, it seems like it creates local database for tests, which is empty and deleted after the emulator is shut down.

When I'm launching `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, it writes `The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.`, which seems about what I want. However, when I'm trying to execute the function, it says `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`, even though I'm initializing `admin` with google service account. I tried to use both project owner credentials and *App engine default service account*

Comment: Please post this as an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue ? I am facing the similar issue "The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production." But I am not getting any data in response. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427487/firebase-emulator-return-empty-data-whereas-working-fine-after-deploying

Comment: @LokeshPandey, unfortunately, I don't remember, Firebase didn't quite fit my goals, so I switched to traditional kind of hosting :(